# AbstractRoutingDatasource share datasource per request Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have followed exactly following website to set up the abstractroutingdatasource

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source

I found that if i dont clear the threadlocal, I would get the cached datasource when i submitted same request for few times (probably one out of five chance would get the cached datasource)

in my code i have commented ClientDatabaseContextHolder.clear() and causes the problem of sharing datasource per requests. Why should i clear the threadLocal? isn't every request in spring boot application is totally independent of each other? why would they sometimes share the value for each other?

```
public class ClientService {

private ClientDao clientDao;

@Autowired
private ClientDatabaseContextHolder ClientDatabaseContextHolder;
// standard constructors

public String getClientName(ClientDatabase clientDb) {
    ClientDatabaseContextHolder.get(); //default should be null if new request, however, sometimes it will get the value of ABC instead of null
    ClientDatabaseContextHolder.set(clientDb); //E.G ABC
    String clientName = this.clientDao.getClientName();
    //ClientDatabaseContextHolder.clear();
    return clientName;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most Web Applications, Spring will create many threads to handle requests simultaneously. Spring can choose any thread and will reuse threads.

In simple terms: `ClientDatabaseContextHolder` only just stores an enum (according to the example) to select a specific database when `ClientDao` calls for a specific database.

It can be seen as a "function parameter" with global variables and with extra steps.

Due to spring's encapsulation, this was one way they chose to do it. You could do this a different way that may make more sense to you.

There is no need to cache this specific value. The only thing to worry about is not recreating connections.

If you want to cache database queries, that's a whole other thing.

Comment: Do you mean the thread will store the value and reuse in other requests?

Comment: I updated the answer. If that still doesn't make any sense, let me know.